# CSS not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, transition

I'm trying to use an opacity transition and it seems to work in all browsers except IE. IE 10 is supposed to support transitions, and it does... sometimes. I can't figure out why my code won't work. The first-letter code does not work in IE either. Is this not supported or am I doing something wrong?

```
<style type="text/css">
    #piccode { 
        opacity:0; 
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s; 
        transition-duration: 1s; 
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s; 
        -ms-transition-duration:1s; 
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    }
    #piccode:hover { 
        opacity: 1; 
    }
    #postbody p:first-letter { 
        letter-spacing:1px; 
        line-height:0.5; 
        font-size: 25px; 
        font-family: 'Lovers Quarrel', cursive; 
    }
    #postbody b { 
        color: #8b5a3c; 
    }
</style>
```

I don't know if it makes a difference, but if I delete the transitions, hovering continues to do nothing. I think my hover might be the problem... I'm sorry if I sound dumb here. I'm entirely self-taught!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transition, you forgot to specify which property to animate (for simplicity I used the [shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) here):

```
#piccode { 
  opacity:0; 
     -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; 
      -ms-transition: opacity 1s; 
       -o-transition: opacity 1s;
          transition: opacity 1s; 
}
```

And for [`first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) the syntax with two colons `::` is recommended (Older browser version should support the single colon syntax as well):

```
#postbody p::first-letter { /* ... */  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Adding a second colon to the first letter code solved the problem with that. However, specifying a property to transition did nothing...

Comment: It worked for me in fiddle but not on the page I was working with. I tried to set a doctype. That didn't work. I assume it's something in the message board I'm trying to code on that's conflicting. I managed to fix the problem with js. Thanks so much for your input! It was super helpful!

Comment: Same happens to me. I believe it is bug of IE10 when you have :first-letter, transitions and hover state.[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YneNX/). I have tried setting different options and nothing.